# Storing multiline RSA Key in .NET core User Secrets (JSON)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, github, .net-core

The recommended way to store secrets (like API keys and passwords) during development of an ASP.NET core 3 application is to use *user secrets*. While this approach works nicely I do have a multiline string which contains an *RSA key*. The key is copied from a provided *.pem* file.

Is there any easy way to store the key in `secrets.json`?

The problem seems to be that *json* does not support multiline strings. Thus simply copying the key into the file does not work. Workarounds like using an array for the different lines of the key does not play nicely with the `Configuration` class and binding retrieved secrets to an `Options`-class.

I have figured out that once I convert the key into a single line string it works. However, the need for a separate tool to convert the key from multiline to single line, seems to me too complex.

By the way, I do need this for building a *GitHub-App*.

Comment: You can use azure keyVault for storing and that works in production also.

Comment: @VikrantSingh sure, but so far I don't have access to azure and would like to keep things local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using a multi-line string with user secrets. You can pass one directly to `dotnet user-secrets`

For example, some Powershell using a here-string:

```bsh
$multiVal = @"
Your
Multi-line 
Text
"@
dotnet user-secrets set "YourKeyName" "$multiVal"
```

Or with embedded new-line character  `` `n ``:

```bsh
dotnet user-secrets "YourKeyName" "Your`nMulti-line`nValue"
```

Or you could read in an entire text-based file:

```bsh
$fileName = "/path/to/file" 
$multiVal = Get-Content $fileName -Raw
dotnet user-secrets set "YourKeyName" "$multiVal"
```

A JSON string property also allows "multi-line" text, just not in the way you're thinking. The literal characters `\` and `n` together inside of a string property will be deserialized as a new-line. For example, the following JSON has a string property with a multi-line value:

```
{
  "YourKeyName": "Your\nMulti-line\nText" 
}
```

You can achieve this in a variety of ways, for example doing a *manual* find-and-replace or with tools like Notepad++. You could also use some Powershell once again:

```bsh
$inputFile = "/path/to/file" 
$multiVal = Get-Content $inputFile -Raw
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
   YourKeyName = $multiVal
}
$outputFile = "/path/to/secrets.json"
$obj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50 | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile
```

**Edit**: you mentioned one of the parameters is not working in the final example. It's possible you are somehow running an older version of powershell (pre 3.0). You can try this instead:

```bsh
$inputFile = "/path/to/file" 
# no -Raw flag 
$multiVal = (Get-Content $inputFile | Out-String)
# or alternatively 
$multiVal = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($inputFile)
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
   YourKeyName = $multiVal
}
$outputFile = "/path/to/secrets.json"
# use redirection instead of Out-File
($obj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50) > $outputFile
```

Now with respect to RSA keys, according to [this answer and its comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/19055) while the RSA spec calls for line breaks within the base-64 encoded payload it's possible that  implementations may allow non-conformance. This means that depending on how you're using it, you *might* be able to get away with stripping out the new-lines entirely. You'd have to try it out to know for sure.

**Edit**: It turns out that `dotnet user-secrets` has/had a [known bug](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18095) where values cannot have a leading `-`. It's fixed now but I think only for 5.0+. I found that a leading space works and I would *think* that the RSA provider shouldn't balk at that. The following should work:

```bsh
dotnet user-secrets set "PKeyPowerShell" " $multiVal"
```

Comment: Thanks! I already removed the newlines and stored the single line in the secrets.json. For me this worked perfectly. I thought there might be an out of the box solution without transforming the key into single line.

Comment: @pinkflodx33 I tried the powershell approach with reading the content of the file into a variable and set that one as user-secrets (your 3. code example), but it results in an error "unrecognized option". Then the whole private key is shown in the shell. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know which option it was complaining about? Raw or FilePath?

Comment: I added an edit with a few variants of the last code block. Hopefully one works for you. You must be on an older powershell somehow

Comment: I'm running Powershell 5.1.19041.1 - the problem was not Get-Content. That works fine. When I output multiVal, I see the proper RSA key. The error comes from dotnet user-secrets. - The obj from your new example looks not right. The resulting json is wrong. Anyway, I would love to go with the way to use dotnet user-secrets. Is that one working for you? What kind of key are you trying with?

Comment: All of the versions I've posted work for me. The dotnet user secrets works perfectly with a large block of text with line breaks in it. Try wrapping the variable passed to dotnet user-secrets in double quotes (see updated answer). As for the wrong json in the later examples, I don't know what you're doing. Can you show the code for the object only (the `$obj=[pscustomobject]` part).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218998/discussion-between-jan-suchotzki-and-pinkfloydx33).

Comment: Unfortunately the BouncyCastle.PemReader doesn't like the first line of the RSA key stored in the pem file: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n But that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: For anyone using user secrets in .NET Framework where an XML file is used, I was able to use &#xA; successfully in place of \n.